# ReactNative how to handle a focus on TextInput into a custom component

Tags: reactjs, events

I have two questions / problems to solve.

I need to create a TextInput custom component to manage CSS, behaviour and icons.

Some code, I keep it simple:

```
// imports

export function CustomTextInput ({
  autoCorrect,
  autoFocus,
  caretHidden,
  contextMenuHidden,
  defaultValue,
  editable,
  enterKeyHint,
  inputMode,
  onFocus
  // ... Much longer list
}) {
  
  // Some code

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        autoCorrect={autoCorrect}
        autoFocus={autoFocus}
        caretHidden={caretHidden}
        contextMenuHidden={contextMenuHidden}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        editable={editable}
        enterKeyHint={enterKeyHint}
        inputMode={inputMode}
        cursorColor={primaryColor}
        onFocus={onFocus}
        // ... Much longer list
    />
    </View>
  )
}
```

First question: do we have a solution to get all "original" props from TextInput into this component without passing everything one by one like I did?

Second question: I would like change the `backgroundColor` when the user take the focus. But I need to keep `onFocus` to pass a custom method.

I hope I am being cristal clear on those problems.

Thank you very much.

For the `onFocus` method I tried an `array` and a coma.